# How can I not snap people's necks (or only snap it a little bit)?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

So the wall-punching augmentation (in the Cybernetic Arm Prosthesis augmentation tree) allows you to punch through weak walls, but will automatically have you snap the neck of anyone standing on the other side of them.

Am I correct in assuming this will ruin a pacifist playthrough?  Is there any way to do a non-lethal wall-punch and only snap his neck a little bit?

Comment: "only snap his neck a little bit" has to be one of my favorite requests of all time...

Comment: agree, that should be put into the title somehow

Comment: Don't punch walls with people behind them?

Comment: Altered title at request, lol.  Also Nick T - that's great once you've gotten the augmentations to see behind walls, but what if you don't have them yet and would like to explore some alternate paths?

Comment: "But I didn't kill it, George. Honest, I found it dead. I was just pettin' it with the fingers while he was walkin' along..."

Comment: "snap his neck a little bit" is hilarious.

Comment: With the augment that allows you to see through walls you could check if somebody is on the other side of the wall. That way you won't have to totally abandon any hope of living out your hate against walls.

Comment: @CruelCow, doesn't that only let you track targets through walls?  I'd have to see them first to know that I'm about to snap their neck.  If I've seen them, I can just leave them and their precious wall be (I guess...).

Comment: the weak wall at the top of derelict row will always kill the guy behind it... even if i used a pistol to shoot the wall down... always ends up dead... =\

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've done this trick on my last playthrough, smashing the wall and knocking out the person on the other side. As I expected, I got Pacifist at the end.

So, in short, no, this technique does not disqualify you for Pacifist. That said, the criteria for Pacifist are quite weird, I think the game is designed to be lenient.

Comment: "But officer, I found him this way, I swear!"

Answer (score 9):

What you can do (instead of wall punching) is to use a revolver with explosive bullets on the wall. It will render the person on the other side unconscious when the wall breaks, instead of killing him (2 rounds AFAIK). It made the Tracer Tong mission extremely easy (playing non-lethal).

Comment: Interesting. Do you know why this works like this?

Comment: I have no idea why it works, the soldier on the other side wasn't even in an alarmed state before the wall broke down on him... I guess the idea is that he was being knocked unconscious by the bricks.

Answer (score 6):

After taking the wall breaking perk, I found myself in the situation of breaking through walls leading the lethal deaths. I noticed that the wall had a health rating, like crates do, taking a indestructible object, a barrel, I threw it against the wall multiple times until it broke, this alerted the guards but this method works without any expenditure of grenades or explosive shots from a revolver.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have a revolver with explosive bullets, you can also toss a frag grenade at the wall.  The wall will come down, but the person on the other side will only be knocked unconscious.

Comment: Explosives?  On a wall?  Who woulda thunk?  Does it really break the walls down?  I wish I had known that when I played the game.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need explosives. It takes a few shots but I was able to break through a wall with my silenced 10mm pistol. I do however have the armor piercing on it but I tried it with my shotgun(not modded) and after about 5 shots I broke through. It did a non lethal knockout on the guy on the other side of wall for those pacifists out there.